# How to print new values without making a new line? (timer)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a timer and it works great. The only problem is that every time a second passes, it prints the time left in seconds in a new line. How do I make it so that instead of printing a new line it just changes what is displayed in the current line?

This is what I have...

```
import time

t = int(input("Time (in seconds): "))

while t > 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
    print(t)

print("TIME DONE")
```

Answer (score 7):

By default [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) prints newline after the given string.
You can use `end='..'` to specify another character instead of newline.

Note that standard output is line buffered. Not printing newline will make the output buffered. You can force it displayed by calling `sys.stdout.flush()` or specify `flush=True` (Python 3.3+)

```py
print(t, end='')
sys.stdout.flush()

# OR

print(t, end='', flush=True)
```

If you want printed text replaced, you can use carriage return (`\r`),

```py
print('\r', t, end='')
# OR
print('\r', t, sep='', end='')  # if you keep leading space printed.
```

Comment: Do you have any idea for the python IDLE?

Comment: @ppwater, carriage return support in idle? I don't have an idea.

Comment: No, it doesn't it prints strange text instead of `\r`

Comment: @ppwater, Seems IDLE doesn't support `\r` (carriage return). Run it in terminal, please. https://bugs.python.org/issue23220